# What is the English equivalent to the proverb "Somebody finds his soup not thick enough, and somebody finds his pearls too small"

Tags: idiom-requests, translation, proverb-requests, russian

What's the equivalent to the Russian proverb *"Somebody finds his soup not thick enough, and somebody finds his pearls too small"*("Кому суп не густ, кому жемчуг мелок")?

It means a situation when one person takes what he has for granted and thus affords himself to complain about the faults of the luxurious things he possesses, whereas somebody, in contrast, doesn't have too many things, sometimes even basic ones, like a good meal. The proverb can be used both literally and refer to something material and figuratively.

Comment: If "It means a situation when ... somebody, in contrast, doesn't have too many things, sometimes even basic ones, like a good meal", then why portray them as complaining? Why not say something like "some people can't afford thick soup"?

Answer (score 12):

Perhaps the nearest is [Chandler's sarcastic complaint in Friends](https://www.digitalspy.com/tv/ustv/a789050/friends-23-phrases-hit-sitcom-gave-us-we-use-every-day-breezy-friend-zone/) season 2: "My wallet is too small for my fifties and my diamond shoes are too tight." This, and particularly the last 6 words, are widely quoted.

The notion of "[first world problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_World_problem)" is similar, denoting things that would be trivial to most of the world's population. Wikipedia says it was coined in 1979 in G. K. Payne's *Built Environment*, and popularised online in 2005, becoming a hashtag and entering dictionaries. It maybe suggests things that are slightly more common and widespread than pearl size, so it's not quite the same.

Comment: Up vote for "first world problems" - I've never heard "diamond shoes."

Comment: An example of a first world problem: "My new TV is too big to fit into my entertainment center"

Comment: The line about fifties is even more ridiculous, given that in US currency, all the bills are the same size, so a fifty (or even a hundred) is no larger than a single.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman It's not the size of the bills, it's the number of them -- he has so many 50's that they don't fit in his wallet.

Answer (score 0):

In the film *Annie Hall*, there is a Woody Allen bit known for quoting an old joke about two old women complaining about being at a fancy mountain resort:

“There's an old joke - um... two elderly women are at a Catskill mountain resort, and one of 'em says, "Boy, the food at this place is really terrible." The other one says, "Yeah, I know; and such small portions."

This joke goes back to at least [1927](https://www.barrypopik.com/index.php/new_york_city/entry/the_food_is_terrible_and_such_small_portions), quite popularized since used as a caption to an illustration in [Bronx Ballads](https://books.google.com/books?id=6rE7AQAAIAAJ&q=mouthful%20poison%20%22small%20portions%22&dq=mouthful%20poison%20%22small%20portions%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=OznzUIz9G4ac2QWu04GgDw).  Being food and luxury related, it shows what somebody can take for granted.

Like StuartF mentioned, this is an example of a first world problem or [luxury problem](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Luxury%20Problem).  The  punchline *"And such small portions!"* is quoted on its own enough to become a stand-alone line for perspective on complaining about something that really isn't that bad.  At least you have food to eat at that terribly pricey restaurant you can afford at the awfully charming vacation spot.

Comment: Henry Rawlinson (Viv Stanshall) did a variant of this - "That was inedible muck, and there wasn't enough of it"

Comment: What the OP is after is a way to portray a situation where each person makes a single complaint. The joke you tell is nice, but it's a different thing. The second speaker makes two complaints, and the paradox is that resolving the second (making the portions bigger) would make things worse judging by the first.

Comment: @RosieF I agree and concede that.  So far no one has a saying that includes the other POV.  I hope this question finds something like the OP's expression since this complaint doesn't end with an element of "but there are starving children playing football with skulls in Kigali."